# C++ - Move constructor of class with a fixed size, c-style array member

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, move-constructor

I have a class with a fixed size, c-style array member, something like [this](https://ideone.com/luzr2D):

```
struct some {
    static const size_t name_length = 64;

    char name[name_length+1];

    some() = default;

    some(const some& s) {
        memcpy(name, s.name, strlen(s.name)+1);
    }

    // other constructors...

    void set_name(const char* s) {
        auto len = strlen(s);
        if (len > name_length) {
            len = name_length;
        }
        memcpy(name, s, len);
        name[len] = '\0';
    }
};
```

Copy constructor works fine, but **how would I implement a move constructor?**

I know I could replace the c-style array with `std::array`, but is there anyway to do this without it?

P.S.: A lot of people are suggesting for me to use the compiler-generated copy/move constructors... Unfortunately, in the real class, I cannot do that because this class has other members and other constructors... I just wanted to know if there were a way to move the fixed-size members. I guess there isn't, and the move constructor will have to just copy the bytes. I wonder if this is what `std::array` does...

Comment: You would implement one by not implementing one. Use `std::string` or `std::array` and let the compiler do it.

Comment: Your move constructor will be the same as your copy constructor.  There's no clever way to "move" a fixed size array.  But why don't you want to use a `std::array`?  It seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: There is nothing to move in this class. You don't need it.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a `std::string` and the rule of zero?

Comment: And if you don't use `std::string`, your class gains nothing from moving.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but if the goal is for the class to hold a nul-terminated C string, the code in `set_name` is wrong. If the string pointed to by `s` is longer than the buffer size, the call to `memcpy` will copy characters from `s` into the buffer up to the limit. The result will be that the text in `name` is not nul terminated.

Comment: I'm not using `std::string` to avoid memory allocations.

Comment: @Petebecker, yeah, this is because I tried to type quickly a minimal working example... the real class is not like that... But thanks!

Comment: if you used `std::string` it was quicker to type :P

Comment: [...] *avoid memory allocations* [...] Probalby interesting to know for you is **short string optimization**. libc for example 10 byte on 32bit systems, 22byte on 64bit systems. I think most names fill fit...

Comment: You don't need to count the non-null `char`s of `name` in the copy (and move) constructor, you can just use a flat `name_length + 1`.

Comment: BTW: Why is `name_length = 64`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I implement a move constructor?

There are no resources owned by this class, no pointer members, so its move constructor is identical to its copy constructor.

Also, you do not need to define the copy constructor manually here, the compiler-generated one does the right thing - member-wise copy:

```
some(const some& s) = default;
```

Alternatively, you can remove both constructors. This will also allow you to initialized your class with aggregate initializer syntax like: `some s = {"it is something"};`.

Comment: Pointers or not has nothing to do with it, though there is a correlation.

Comment: @Deduplicator That is a statement too strong to be correct. In this specific case your statement is plainly incorrect.

Comment: "There are no resources owned by this class" is probably a better phrasing

Comment: @Caleth I take that line.

Answer (score 4):

As your class doesn't own any resource directly (nor indirectly through a member), don't waste your time writing move-ctor and / or move-assignment, there's no advantage to be gained:
They have to do the same as the copy-variants anyway.

Also, writing your own custom copy-ctor is a waste of time, as the default one is perfectly fine, and has the disadvantage of making the class non-trivial. Though if you have to be demonstrative, explicitly default it in-class to preserve triviality.

As an aside, consider whether you need 0-termination at all, or can use 0-padded sequences of maximum length instead. Just one more than a power of two is quite an awkward size.